# How to format excel big numbers in rounding them with two significant digits

Tags: excel, numbers, format, rounding

I would like to format big numbers in Excel in such a way that only the two most significant digits are displayed. Remaining digits would be padded with additional zero.

Example:

1234567 would be displayed as 1 200 000
and
1234 would be displayed as 1 200

Using the format # # " 000" would display 1234567 as 1 235 000 but this is not what I am looking for because it does not scale to one-digit-less numbers. Solutions like 1.2 M is not what I am looking for neither.

The same format should work for both examples. I don't want to round the number, but round the displayed value only (the format).

Comment: How does # # " 000" display 1234567 as 1 234 000? Can you give an example of the formatting? All this seems to do is concatenate three "0" on the end

Comment: I'm willing to bet that doing exactly what you want with the "Format Cells -> Number" menu cannot be accomplished, however there are lots of ways it could be accomplished with Visual Basic or with referenced cells (see my solution). If you could give us the context of the question, we may be able to offer alternative suggestions.

Comment: Sorry I made a mystake. The format # # " 000" displays 1234567 as 1 235 000.

Comment: did you read my comment above? Can you explain to us 'why' you want to do this? Maybe then we can help you.

Comment: I would be interested in a solution as well. But AFAIK, this is not possible in Excel.

Comment: @mzuba you might want to vote for that question then...

Comment: @Heyji What do you mean? I did upvote the question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use conditional formatting as described here:
http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel

so if your number is over 100 and less than 1000 - `# # " 00"`
over 1000 and less than 10000 - `# # " 000"`

etc etc

Edit - I know the tutorial is for some Mac version of excel, but Conditionl Formatting is still there in my Excel2010

Comment: the format # # " 00" does not display 123 as 120 as far as I know.

Comment: what about `# # " 0"` ? I think I just counted zeroes wrong

Comment: Neither. Maybe you could test it before submitting an answer.

Comment: I was basing my suggestion on your initial assertion that `# # " 000"` formatted 1234567 as 1234000. That is not the case. Maybe you could include the actual format you used to acheive that in your question? And the use of conditional formatting was the main point of my answer, not the specific format codes to be used.

Comment: the format # # " 000" displays 1 235 000 actually. I have updated my post accordingly. I would like it to display 1 200 000.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your value is in A1, the following formula returns the correct result on both of your numbers

`=ROUND(A1/POWER(10,LEN(A1)-2),0)*POWER(10,LEN(A1)-2)`

In other words, get the number of digits...

`LEN(A1)`

Get 10^(Number of digits-2)

`POWER(10,LEN(A1)-2)`

Divide your number by that number

`A1/POWER(10,LEN(A1)-2),0)`

Round that number to get rid of the decimal

`ROUND(A1/POWER(10,LEN(A1)-2),0)`

And then multiply by that number to get your final result

`=ROUND(A1/POWER(10,LEN(A1)-2),0)*POWER(10,LEN(A1)-2)`

You can then use the TEXT formatting to get the format you want. Something like...

`=TEXT(ROUND(A1/POWER(10,LEN(A1)-2),0)*POWER(10,LEN(A1)-2),"# ###")`

Will probably meet your needs

EDIT: As mentioned in the comment, IF your original value is in a different cell, you can also use the following function for formatting

`=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,2),REPT("0",LEN(A1)-2))`

Comment: As I said, I don't want to round the value, I want to round its displayed/formatted value. It means that if cell A1 contains the value 126, the displayed value should be 120. And if the cell A2 is linked to A1 by the formula 2*A1, A2 should display 252 (or 250 if formatted the same way, but not 240 !)

Comment: So you want the value in place to be `1234567` but displayed as `1200000`? I can see how my solution would not satisfy. Another option for displaying the data in a different cell would be `=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A5,2),REPT("0",LEN(A5)-2))` but I'm guessing that will have the same problem as my first solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the cells you wish to format in this fashion contain **values** rather than **formulas**, select the cells and run this tiny macro:

```
Sub PhancyPhormat()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, le As Long
    Dim DQ As String
    DQ = Chr(34)
        For Each r In Selection
            s = CStr(r.Value)
            le = Len(s)
            For i = 3 To le
            Mid(s, i, 1) = "0"
        Next i
        phony = DQ & s & DQ & ";;;"
        r.NumberFormat = phony
    Next r
End Sub
```

You would need to re-run the macro if your change the values.